# How to do boustrophedon typesetting?

Tags: right-to-left

This is spurred from [writing in Meander / Greek Key pattern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/637430). Ancient Greek writing was in boustrophedon style where one line was left-to-right, the next was right-to-left, the next was left-to-right and so on.

Can this be done in LaTeX? And if so, how?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56989

Comment: Also, the famous `chickenize` package.

Comment: And http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134356

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you for your input. I had no idea that ther was so much boustrophedon code available. I must adtmit, though, that I like David Carlisle's answer in https://tex.stackechange.com/a/56989